# Dúvida acerca da propriedade "animation-name"

Tags: css, animação

Estou estudando todas as propriedades do CSS3 e me veio uma dúvida acerca da propriedade **animation-name**.

O valor que é dado a esta propriedade é personazável ou é um valor pré-definido pela linguagem?

A dúvida veio depois de ler um código que tinha o seguinte conteúdo:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: mymove;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: mymove;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
```

Na qual me fez pensar que o valor **mymove** é um valor definido pelo usuário e não um pré-definido pela linguagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, esse é um nome customizado que deve referenciar o nome dado à diretiva `@keyframe`. De acordo com a especificação da W3:

> A propriedade **animation-name** define uma lista de animações que se aplicam. Cada nome é usado para selecionar o *keyframe* na regra que fornece os valores de propriedade para a animação. Se o nome não corresponder a nenhum *keyframe* na regra, não há propriedades a ser animada e a animação não será executada. Além disso, se o nome de animação é **none**, então não haverá nenhuma animação. Isso pode ser usado para substituir as animações vindas em cascata. Se múltiplas animações tentam modificar a mesma propriedade, então a animação mais próxima do fim da lista de nomes ganha.

Os valores possíveis para essa propriedade são:

`none` -  Nenhum *keyframe*  é especificado, então não há animação. Qualquer outra propriedade de animação especificada não terá efeito.

`<custom-ident>` - A animação usará os *keyframes* especifiados pela propriedade (separados por vírgula), se existirem. Se tais keyframes não existirem, não há animação.

Veja o seguinte exemplo: São especificados três keyframes - `slide-right, slide-up, slide-down`. Porém dois deles alteram a mesma propriedade (margin-top). Se a ordem da declaração dos keyframes `slide-up` e `slide-down` for alterada na propriedade `animation-name`, vale aquele declarado por último.

```css
div {
  animation-name: slide-right, slide-up, slide-down;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 110px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 110px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    margin-top: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-top: 110px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: #ff0000;"></div>
```

Leia a especificação completa em: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation-name

Comment: Obrigado MarcusVinicius, outra dúvida acerca de um trecho do seu texto:

**Se múltiplas animações tentam modificar a mesma propriedade, então a animação mais próxima do fim da lista de nomes ganha.**

Então isso significa que um elemento só pode receber um tipo de animação, e as anteriores seriam descartadas? Isto é, o padrão é somente uma animação por elemento?

Comment: Não, você pode combinar as animações, mas se várias delas modificam por exemplo `margin-left` então há conflito. Nesse caso, a última especificada que funciona.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Então se eu tiver três **keyframes slide1, keyframes slide2, keyframes slide3**  ele irá executar somente a **keyframe slide3**?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta, fiz um exemplo lá. Altere a ordem dos keyframes slide-down e slide-up e verá que somente um dos dois funciona, pois eles alteram a mesma propriedade (margin-top). Já o slide-right sempre funciona, independente da ordem, pois não tem conflito de propriedades com os outros dois.

Comment: Entendi. No caso está funcionando apenas o **slide-right** e o **slide-up** correto?

Pois, se fosse apenas o **slide-right** o **keyframe** não desceria, mas iria apenas para a direita ou vice-versa.